# Accessing QBCOCustomObject retrieved from QBRequest inaccessible outside of QBRequest

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I am trying to access whatever record was returned from my QBRequest and send it to a separate function (in this case, I'm trying to set whatever I got from the request, convert its contents to strings, and then display in cells). However, I am unable to do this by direct referencing outside of the QBRequest nor setting the object to outside variable.

```
var posts = [QBCOCustomObject]()

func queryForPost(city: String) -> [QBCOCustomObject] {

    let requestParameters = NSMutableDictionary();
    [requestParameters.setObject(city, forKey: "Location")];


    QBRequest.objectsWithClassName("UserFeed", extendedRequest: requestParameters, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, record, page) in


        print(record![0].fields!.allValues[0])
        print(record![1].fields!.allValues[0])
        //the two above prints return the desired values
        self.posts = record! 

        }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse) in
            // Handle error here
            NSLog("error QBRequest - objectsWithClassName")
    })

    print(self.posts.count, "POSTS.COUNT") //can't access posts or record - this returns 0, and THEN returns whatever print functions are inside the QBRequest. 

    print(self.posts, "POSTS")

    return self.posts 
}
```

"print(self.posts.count, "POSTS.COUNT")" returns 0, and THEN returns whatever print functions are inside the QBRequest. Seems as if the QBRequest is performing after going through the whole function. Very confused and not sure how to fix this...
Been struggling with this for a while now :( If anybody could provide some guidance I would very much appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance!

Lance

Comment: `objectsWithClassName` completes asynchronously and invokes the `successBlock` with the results.  This means you can't `return` the value from the function, since when the function returns the data hasn't yet been retrieved.  You should pass a closure to your `queryForPost` function and invoke that closure in the success block in order to process the posts

Comment: You need to do this : http://prntscr.com/clornu

Comment: Thank you for your input! 
@Paulw11 - I am not sure how to pass a closure to my queryForPost function, as I've been searching the QuickBlox documentation and couldn't figure out how to do so.. I am fairly new to QuickBlox and am in the learning process so I apologize in advance if the answer is trivial.

Comment: @DeveloperRoadies - objectsWithClassName is a void return so returning the post will not work - is there a way to work around this in your solution? 

Again, thank you both so much in advance!

Comment: It is nothing to do with QuickBlox.  The QuickBlox function already takes a closure - it is the bit after `successBlock`.  You need to change your `queryForPost` method accept a closure and then call that closure from with in `successBlock`.  See the Swift book from Apple